# jquery switch element classes

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-animate

Please take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUd27/7/

What I need:

- There are several elements. One of them is active and visible.
- If I hover over any inactive element, it becomes visible and active. The previously active element becomes inactive.
- On mouseout, nothing happens - the last hovered element stays active.

My problems:

- The first active element always stays active (in DOM?). It becomes invisible, but on next mouseover nothing happens.
- Other elements don't behave as they should. If one of them is active, on next mousein it becomes invisible.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to the solution, I think.

Instead of doing this:-

```
$(".slogan_switch_item:not(.active)").hover(function(){
   ...
});
```

... do this:-

```
$(".slogan_switch_item:not(.active)").live('hover',function(){
   ...
});
```

I managed to get it working properly by changing this one line.

Comment: Man, I was trying to use live(), but i'm so noob in Jquery and JS, that i didn't found the right syntax! Thank you so much!

Comment: hm, and how i prevent it from blinking if i move the mouse over the buttons fast and randomly?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. It might help you find an easier solution (possibly using css transforms?) :)

http://jsfiddle.net/4yEsN/